# Remove Number Label from \sectionmark

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

There are a number of questions on the site that come somewhat close to this one, but don't seem to solve my problem. I'm working in Overleaf for the following, if that means anything.

I'm trying to use `\sectionmark` to set up a page style that includes the name of the current section. However, when I use it in what seems to be the right way, the header includes the number of the section, which I don't want. That is, for example in the screenshot below, it says "1    Saskatchewan / [page number]" and I'd like to remove the "1".

Screenshot:
[image]

Corresponding MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% PREAMBLE ---------------------------------------------------------------------

% Attempt to redefine the \sectionmark command
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{\thesection}{}}

% Formatting headings
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Huge}{}{0pt}{\flushleft \thesection / #1}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark} / \thepage}
}

% Only in to remove warning about head height
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% BEGIN DOCUMENT ---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Saskatchewan}
\lipsum[1-8]

\section{Alberta}
\lipsum[7-15]

\end{document}
```

I don't really understand why I'm getting this number in here, but maybe it has something to do with the redefinition of the section format with `fancyhdr`? Any help removing it would be greatly appreciated.

Note: One thing I've tried is using the `xstring` package and its `StrBehind` command, but I think the character between the number and heading is some special character as this hasn't worked. In any case, in the full document I'm writing, the section title includes an image in between the two, so `xstring` may not work there even if it works for this MWE.

EDIT: For those interested in the future, this turned out to be a problem with Overleaf. Specifically the 2020 compiler image had a funny interaction with one of the style packages used here, which is absent in the 2021 compiler. Thanks to Overleaf tech support for being kind enough to explain this.

Comment: For the `Note`, you stated above, please ask another question.

Comment: @mmr The note I left at the end wasn't intended to be a separate question, only a statement about a thing I'd tried that helped other folks with similar-ish problems but hadn't solved my particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

You made the rigid page style using `\pagestyle{plain}`. Remove this and Try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% PREAMBLE ---------------------------------------------------------------------

% Attempt to redefine the \sectionmark command
%\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{{#1}{}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}{ / \thepage}} % Change is here
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{}} 


% Formatting headings
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Huge}{}{0pt}{\flushleft \thesection / #1}

% Page style
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \fancyhf{}
% \fancypagestyle{plain}{
%     \fancyhf{}
%     \fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark} / \thepage}
% }

% Only in to remove warning about head height
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% BEGIN DOCUMENT ---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Saskatchewan}
\lipsum[1-8]

\section{Alberta}
\lipsum[7-15]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @mmr. This code probably works, but more importantly it gave me ideas for a couple of things to try. It turns out that the *only* change I had to make was to move the redefinition of `\sectionmark` to after the inclusion of the `fancyhdr` package (and also change the mark content from `\thesection` to `#1` to get the section name instead of the number). So, any idea why this change would do the trick? Also, was there some reason you commented about the use of the `plain` page style? Thanks again.

Comment: Another thing that seems true of this answer is that it only contains one page style. If I need other pages styles, or need to define a custom page style, how can I still get this to work? Oddly enough the above change alone was inadequate in my actual document (my non-MWE).